# Forward to another controller/action from module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing a module for `ACL` in `ZF2`, And I am almost done with it.

The point where I am stucked is when user is not authorised to access the requested page, I want to **forward** the user to a page showing `403` message.

I have tried **redirecting** user to `403` but it updates `URL`, so now I am tring to **forward** user.

All I want to do is from `Module.php`. I have tried below code -

**Module.php**

```
if (!$isAllowed) {
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('forward')->dispatch('acl');
}
```

Using this I got following error -

> Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Exception\DomainException' with message 'Forward plugin requires a controller that implements InjectApplicationEventInterface'

I have also tried to implement `Acl` controller with `InjectApplicationEventInterface`, But the issue remains same.

Can you please explain how to `Forward` to another `Action` from `Module.php`?
Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I don't think you can use `forward` plugin for that, or that you should. Why not use a proper redirect (changing location) instead?

Comment: I can't redirect. It is requirment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to listen for the dispatch event. You can update the route match during this event to match a controller/action pair which is defined by yourself to render the 403 page.

In code:

```
use MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $acl = $app->getServiceManager()->get('ACL'); // get your ACL here

        if (!$acl->isAllowed()) {
            $em = $app->getEventManager();
            $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function($e) {
                $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();

                $routeMatch->setParam('controller', 'my-403-controller');
                $routeMatch->setParam('action', 'my-403-action');
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Forwarding is a pattern to dispatch a controller *when another controller has already been dispatched*. That is not your case, as I read it from your question. So don't use the forward plugin, but modify the route match before it's dispached.

Answer (score 0):

You can not forword but redirect to your 403 page as follow:

```
if (!$acl->isAllowed()) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/403page');
    $response->setStatusCode(403);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to send information to user that he is in restricted zone without the update of url you have to:

1. Change layout which shows restricted area message.
2. Leave original layout and just switch templates for your action so it shows restricted area message.

After one of this actions you just change Response to 403. 
If that`s what you want its simple to do. For any action in your controller you want to send 403 status just use:

```
 $viewModel->setTemplate('partial/noRights');
 $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode('403');
 return $viewModel;
```

or if you want to change layout for your custom one:

```
 $this->layout('layout/custom');
 $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode('403');
 return $viewModel;
```

You can of course do it to in bootstrap section of your module adding listener on event_dispatch and there check if $acl->isAllowed() after that do your changes which i wrote above. Example:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $acl = $app->getServiceManager()->get('ACL'); // get your ACL here

    if (!$acl->isAllowed()) {
        $eventManager = $app->getEventManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function($e) {
            $controller = $e->getTarget(); //controller`s action which triggered event_dispatch
            $controller->getResponse()->setStatusCode('403');
            $controller->layout('layout/custom');
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented ACL, 
I created my own AUTH module for authorization and authentication.
In that module I created ACL plugin.. something like below

//Module.php

```
 /**
     * This method is called once the MVC bootstrapping is complete
     * 
     * @param \Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e
     */
    public function onBootstrap(Event $e) 
    {
        $services = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration'), 101);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
     */
    public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e) 
    {        
        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
                ->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('AclPlugin')
                ->checkAcl($e); //Auth/src/Auth/Controller/AclPlugin      
    }
```

//Auth/src/Auth/Controller/AclPlugin

```
namespace Auth\Controller\Plugin;

/**
 * load libraries here
 */
class AclPlugin extends AbstractPlugin implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface 
{
    /*
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */

    protected $em;
    protected $sm;

    /**
     * @param Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     * @return string
     */
public function checkAcl($e) 
    {

        $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $action = $matches->getParam('action', 'index');

       if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission)) {


            return;

        } else {
            $matches->setParam('controller', 'Auth\Controller\User'); // redirect
            $matches->setParam('action', 'accessdenied');

            return;
        }

}

/// rest of the code here

}
```