# zf2 acl forwarding to login form

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2, acl, forward

I would like to forward non-authenticated users (guest) to a login form.

When working with redirect, I need to redirect the guest users from the page they're looking for to the login page; and then redirect them back again.

Example:

(guest visits) mySite/controller/action?var1=xxx&var2=yyy

(AclService redirects) mySite/login

(AuthService redirects) mySite/controller/action?var1=xxx&var2=yyy

And all this can only work (I guess) using session variables.

**My idea instead, is to forward user to mySite/login. When the authentication is successfull, the only thing I need to do is to redirect to the current URL.**
The advantage of this behaviour is that if the user clicks the browser's back button, the page remains the same (mySite/controller/action?var1=xxx&var2=yyy).

Here my code:

in module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){

$app = $e->getApplication();
$sm  = $app->getServiceManager();
$acl = $sm->get('AclService');
$e -> getApplication()-> getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,array($acl, 'checkAcl'),-10);

}
```

in my AclService, checkAcl function

```
[...]

if (!$this->acl ->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)){

   //when my AuthService->hasIdentity() returns false, the the role is guest
   if($role=='guest'){ 
      $controllerClass = get_class($e->getTarget());
         //this prevents nested forwards
         if($controllerClass!='Auth\Controller\Auth2Controller'){
         $e->setResult($e->getTarget()->forward()->dispatch('Auth\Controller\Auth2',array('action'=>'index')));
          }

    }
    else{...}
}
```

And then in my AuthService, I use this function (called in mysite/login) to redirect authenticated users

```
//if the login page has ben forwarded
if($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller')!='Auth\Controller\Auth2'
{
$url=$this->Config['webhost'].$e->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
return $e->getTarget()->redirect()->toUrl($url);
}
//if the request comes directly from a login/register attempt
else{return $e->getTarget()->redirect()->toRoute('user_home');}
```

What do you think about it? It makes sense?

Do you know a better approach?

Comment: I'd suggest not to redirect, but show a login form right away.

Comment: Hi akond, what do you mean? My approach is to check acl on dispatch event and if the user isn't authenticated to FORWARD/DISPATCH the request to the login form Controller/action. I use Redirect function only when the user autenticates succesfully. How can I show a login form on dispatch? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question:

No, it makes no sense. That's because

> Forwarding is a pattern to dispatch a controller when another
>   controller has already been dispatched
>   ([Forward to another controller/action from module.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651959/forward-to-another-controller-action-from-module-php))

Therefore, the acl check is partially useless because anything placed into a protected page will be executed before the forwarding.
This means that if I have a user page (controller) designed for authenticated users only and I call a function like:

```
$name=$this->getUserName($userId);
```

I will get an error message because the var $userId is supposed to be setted during the authentication process. And so on...

---

**Anyway,I found a better solution with a completely different behaviour but the same result (obviously without the issue described above).**

However, since my original question was very specific,for the sake of clarity I would like to explain better **the prefixed goal**:

I got an acl script that runs before dispathcing and redirects the user to a login form if they're not authenticated (role=guest).

**When users send their credential via the login form and they get authenticated, I want to perform a dynamic reidirect depending on how they reached the form**.

**The dynamic redirect should follow theese conditions:**

1. When users reach the form via www.site.com/login, once authenticated they should be redirected to www.site.com/user_home
2. When users reach the form via www.site.com/controller/action/param?var=xxx&var2=yyy[...], once authenticated they should be redirected to the same url without loosing any parameter.
3. Once users are authenticated, they shoud not be able to reach the page www.site.com/login (because is useless). This means users looking for this page shoud be redirected elsewhere.

But I also started from the assumption that **"redirect is bad"**:

4. If not reached directly, there should not be any trace of www.site.com/login into the browser history.
   This because the browser's back button could screw up anything said in point 2 (conflict). Example:

   - I reach the page site.com/user/post/2016?tag=foo but I'm not logged in or session has expired
   - Then I get redirected to www.site.com/login where I fill up the authentication form and submit it
   - Once authenticated, I get redirected again to site.com/user/post/2016?tag=foo
   - BUT, if I go back via the browser's button, then the origin of my request is www.site.com/login and, as defined in point 1 and 3,
     I'll be redirected to www.site.com/user_home loosing the ability to return to site.com/user/post/2016?tag=foo (if not via History). (And this is the reason why I was trying to work with the forward plugin)

**The solution I found to achieve this goal is using the redirect plugin in addition to a do-it-yourself forwarding process which works with the MVC's Routemach.**

I started coding following this samsonasik's tutorial: https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/zend-framework-2-working-with-authenticationservice-and-db-session-save-handler/

The main difference from samsonasik's code is that I added a service called authService which handles authentication-related functions separately.
This just to make the code more readable/reusable since I need some custom logic (related to my application design) to be executed on authentication.

Here the main sections of my structure:

```
Application
Auth
    ->service
             ->authService
             ->aclService
Guest
     ->Controller
                 ->guestHomeController
                                      ->loginAction
                                      ->singUpAction
                                      ->...
                 ->...
User
    ->Controller
                ->userHomeController
                ->...
```

Anything inside the guest module is supposed to be accessible to public (role=guest) but not to already authenticated users (according to point 3 above).

And finally, the code:

path: Auth/Module.php

```
namespace Auth;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{

  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $acl = $sm->get('aclService');

    $acl->initAcl();
    $e -> getApplication() -> getEventManager() -> attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($acl, 'checkAcl'));
  }

  [...]
}
```

path: Auth/src/Auth/Service/AclService.php

```
namespace Auth\Service;

use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource as Resource;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;


class AclService  {

protected $authService;
protected $config;
protected $acl;
protected $role;


    public function __construct($authService,$config)
    {
        if(!$this->acl){$this->acl=new Acl();}
        $this->authService = $authService;
        $this->config = $config;
    }


    public function initAcl()
    {
       $this->acl->addRole(new Role('guest'));
       [...]

       $this->acl->addResource(new Resource('Guest\Controller\GuestHome'));
       [...]

       $this->acl->allow('role', 'controller','action');
       [...]
    }


   public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e)
    {
      $controller=$e -> getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller');
      $action=$e -> getRouteMatch()->getParam('action');
      $role=$this->getRole();

      if (!$this->acl ->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action)){

        //if user isn't authenticated...
        if($role=='guest'){
          //set current route controller and action (this doesn't modify the url, it's non a redirect)
          $e -> getRouteMatch()->setParam('controller', 'Guest\Controller\GuestHome');
          $e -> getRouteMatch()->setParam('action', 'login');
        }//if

        //if user is authenticated but has not the permission...
        else{
          $response = $e -> getResponse();
          $response -> getHeaders() -> addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/404');
          $response -> setStatusCode(404);
        }//else
      }//if
    }

   public function getRole()
   {
   if($this->authService->hasIdentity()){
   [...]
   }
   else{$role='guest';}
   return $role;
   }

   [...]

}
```

path: Guest/src/Guest/Controller/GuestHomeController.php

```
namespace Guest\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Form\Factory;

class GuestHomeController extends AbstractActionController
{

    protected $authService;
    protected $config;
    protected $routeName;

    public function __construct($authService, $config, $routeMatch)
    {
        $this->authService = $authService;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
    }


    public function loginAction()
    {

      $forwardMessage=null;

      //When users DOESN'T reach the form via www.site.com/login (they get forwarded), set a message to tell them what's going on
      if($this->routeName!='login'){
        $forwardMessage='You must be logged in to see this page!!!';
      }

      //This could probably be moved elsewhere and be triggered (when module is "Guest") on dispatch event with maximum priority (predispatch)
      if ($this->authService->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->dynamicRedirect();
      }

      $factory = new Factory();
      $form = $factory->createForm($this->config['LoginForm']);

      $request=$this->getRequest();

      if ($request->isPost()) {

        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

          $dataform = $form->getData();
          $result=$this->authService->authenticate($dataform);

          //result=status code
          if($result===1){$this->dynamicRedirect();}
          else{...}
        }//$form->isValid()
      }//$request->isPost()


      $viewModel = new ViewModel();
      $viewModel->setVariable('form', $form);
      $viewModel->setVariable('error', $forwardMessage);

      return $viewModel;
    }


    public function dynamicRedirect()
    {
      //if the form has been forwarded
      if($this->routeName!='login'){
        $url=$this->config['webhost'].$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
      }
      else{return $this->redirect()->toRoute('userHome');}//else
    }

    [...]
}
```

I will update this post if I find some other issues but for now it works like a charm.

P.S.: Hope my English results readable. :-)